# datetime not working in xml

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am using OpenERP-7.0 and Ubuntu-10.04.

Following code is working fine in 6.0 & 6.1 but it's giving error in 7.0

Here is my code:

```
   <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_leave_not_accounted">
        <field name="name">Leaves to be Accounted</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">hr.holidays</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="domain">[('date_from','&gt;=',(datetime.date.today()-relativedelta(weeks=1)).strftime('Y-%m-%d')),('holiday_status_id.name','in',['Annual','Termination','Resignation'])]</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="hr_holidays.view_holiday_simple"/>
    </record>
```

I am facing following error:

`7.0/server/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 241, in safe_eval
    return eval(test_expr(expr, _SAFE_OPCODES, mode=mode), globals_dict, locals_dict)
  File "", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined`

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: note: there is a new SO-like forum for OpenERP on http://help.openerp.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use only time in XML Parsing.

> [('date','<',time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))]

So you have revised your code from V6.1 to V7.0

Answer (score 0):

In OpenERP 7 it is `DateTime.today()` not `datetime.date.today()`.

Comment: I already tried it, but it's not working. Facing error "NameError: name 'DateTime' is not defined".

Answer (score 0):

use `context_today()` instead of `datetime.date.today()` in 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work:

```
<field name="domain">[('date_from', '&lt;', (context_today()-datetime.timedelta(weeks=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))]</field>
```